Deep validation of a C++ concept
Apparently, C++ concepts are only shallow.
#include <concepts>

template<class T>
T add(T a, T b)
{ return a + b;}

template<class T>
concept addable = requires(T a, T b)
{
    { add(a, b) } -> std::same_as<T>;
};

struct foo{};

static_assert(addable<int>);
static_assert(addable<foo>);  // Passes?!

int main()
{
    add(foo{}, foo{});  // Will not compile
}

Would it be possible somehow make evaluation of addable instantiate the template, so foo no longer appears addable? It is possible to introduce a constraint on the add template, but I am looking for a more general approach:

The compiler finds that the only match is a template
The compiler tries to instantiate the template
Instantiation fails somewhere down the expansion tree, and the concept evaluates to false

This is different of what is being asked in C++20: Validate Template Bodies Against Concepts, which wants the consumer of a concept only to access what the concept explicitly provides. Performing a deep evaluation of addable here is actually nothing more than a regular template instantiation. Thus, the goal is to force an instantiation to happen at the time of concept evaluation.

Is your question whether it's possible to do this in the current C++ language? Or are you asking about the possibility of changing the specification of C++?

I have actually found a solution. If the question is reopened, I can write an answer.
